# Can I Output a Raw String in LESS?

Tags: less

I am interested in getting a small portion of my LESS file to appear in my processed CSS file without having to be recognized as valid LESS.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

LESS has an [escape syntax](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping) that uses double-quoted strings prefixed with `~`, will that work?

In the documentation example:

```
.class {
  filter: ~"ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff()";
}
```

gets output as

```
.class {
  filter: ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff();
}
```